# How to find out the machine in the cluster which stores a given element in RDD and send a message to it?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to know if in an RDD, for example, `RDD = {"0", "1", "2",... "99999"}`, can I find out the machine in the cluster which stores a given element (e.g.: `100`)?

And then in shuffle, can I aggregate some data and send it to the certain machine? I know that the partition of RDD is transparent for users but could I use some method like key/value to achieve that?

Comment: Question is why do you need this and do you mean by "send message"? If RDD has a partitioner you can find exact partition but you should never think about the physical machine.

Comment: @zero323 for example, initially the elements in RDD are (a,a),(b,b),...(z,z), and (a,a)~(d,d) are in a partition P1, and (e,e)~(h,h) are in P2. Then in a map, (m,m)=>(a,e) is output, then I want to send (a,e) to the partion of (a,a)and(e,e). I know a reduce can make it, but I don't want to break the initial partition. That is, I just want to add (a,e) to the partition P1 and P2.Is there any possible way to make it？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking the answer is no or at least not with RDD API. If you can express your logic using graphs then you can try message based API in GraphX or Giraph. If not then using Akka directly instead of Spark could be a better choice.

Still, there are some workarounds but I wouldn't expect high performance. Lets start with some dummy data:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val toPairs = (s: Range) => s.map(_.toChar.toString)

val rdd: RDD[(Int, String)] = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (0, toPairs(97 to 100)), // a-d
  (1, toPairs(101 to 107)), // e-k
  (2, toPairs(108 to 115)) // l-s
)).flatMap{ case (i, vs) => vs.map(v => (i, v)) }
```

and partition it using custom partitioner:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.Partitioner

class IdentityPartitioner(n: Int) extends Partitioner {
  def numPartitions: Int = n
  def getPartition(key: Any): Int = key.asInstanceOf[Int]
}

val partitioner = new IdentityPartitioner(4)
val parts = rdd.partitionBy(partitioner)
```

Now we have RDD with 4 partitions including one empty:

```
parts.mapPartitionsWithIndex((i, iter) => Iterator((i, iter.size))).collect
// Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((0,4), (1,7), (2,8), (3,0))
```

- The simplest thing you can do is to leverage partitioning itself. First a dummy function and a helper:

  ```scala
  // Dummy map function
  def transform(s: String) =
    Map("e" -> "x", "k" -> "y", "l" -> "z").withDefault(identity)(s)

  // Map String to partition
  def address(curr: Int, s: String) = {
    val m = Map("x" -> 3, "y" -> 3, "z" -> 3).withDefault(x => curr)
    (m(s), s)
  }
  ```

  and "send" data:

  ```scala
  val transformed: RDD[(Int, String)] = parts
    // Emit pairs (partition, string)
    .map{case (i, s) => address(i, transform(s))}
    // Repartition
    .partitionBy(partitioner)

  transformed
    .mapPartitionsWithIndex((i, iter) => Iterator((i, iter.size)))
    .collect
  // Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((0,4), (1,5), (2,7), (3,3))
  ```
- another approach is to collect "messages":

  ```scala
  val tmp = parts.mapValues(s => transform(s))

  val messages: Map[Int,Iterable[String]] = tmp
    .flatMap{case (i, s) => {
       val target = address(i, s)
       if (target != (i, s)) Seq(target) else Seq()
     }}
    .groupByKey
    .collectAsMap
  ```

  create broadcast

  ```scala
  val messagesBD = sc.broadcast(messages)
  ```

  and use it to send messages:

  ```scala
  val transformed = tmp
    .filter{case (i, s) => address(i, s) == (i, s)}
    .mapPartitionsWithIndex((i, iter) => {
      val combined = iter ++ messagesBD.value.getOrElse(i, Seq())
      combined.map((i, _))
    }, true)

  transformed
    .mapPartitionsWithIndex((i, iter) => Iterator((i, iter.size)))
    .collect

  // Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((0,4), (1,5), (2,7), (3,3))
  ```

---

Note the following line:

```
val combined = iter ++ messagesBD.value.getOrElse(i, Seq())
```

`messagesBD.value` is the entire broadcast data, which is actually a `Map[Int,Iterable[String]]`, but then `getOrElse` method returns only the data that was mapped to `i` (if available).

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I do have some similar problems in Graphx. In an graph G, during each iteration some new edges (u,v) are output, if I want to send (u,v) to the partition of u and v. Could message API in Graphx make it and reduce unneccessary message passing?

Comment: Nope, GraphX is designed to handle graphs with static topology.