# Spark Scala def with yield

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In [SO 33655920](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655920/when-to-use-mapparitions-and-mappartitionswithindex) I come across the below, fine.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
def f(iterator): yield sum(iterator)
rdd.mapPartitions(f).collect()
```

In Scala, I cannot seem to get the the def in the same shorthand way. The equivalent is? I have searched and tried but to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sum values in the partition you can write something like

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 4, 2)
def f(i: Iterator[Int]) = Iterator(i.sum)
rdd.mapPartitions(f).collect()
```

Answer (score 2):

`yield sum(iterator)` in Python sums the elements of the iterator. The similar way of doing this in Scala would be:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3, 4), 2)
rdd.mapPartitions(it => Iterator(it.sum)).collect()
```

Comment: right, also an excdellent answer. so I assume I can make the it.sum more complicated.