# Spark - How to consume Spark partitions by index

Tags: apache-spark

Is there a way to consume partitions based on the index count?

Am able to find the total number of Spark Partitions using the following **`API`**

```
rdd.partitions.size
```

Currently, the partitions are consumed using `rdd.forEachPartition` but is there a way to consume the partition by index?

Answer (score 0):

Check out spark rdd [mapPartitionsWithIndex](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#mapPartitionsWithIndex(scala.Function2,%20boolean,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag)). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655920/when-to-use-mapparitions-and-mappartitionswithindex) should also useful.