# Copy partial data from one partition to another partition in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-1.5

I have a use case where I start partitioning my data based on a key.
All data belonging to a key stays on one partition.
e.g.

Key1 -> Partition1
Key2 -> Partition2

Now After sometime I may need to merge the key1 and key2. Hence 
I just want to transfer all data from key2 to key1 i.e. from partition2 to partition1. Is it possible in apache spark? I don't want to repartition everything as it is costly for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Spark, can I find out the machine in the cluster which stores a given element in RDD and then send message to it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547142/in-spark-can-i-find-out-the-machine-in-the-cluster-which-stores-a-given-element)

Comment: can you share you code ?